# Why we cannot load immediate value into SRAM in AVR microcontrollers?

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, avr

It is possible to load or copy immediate value i.e. any integer into General purpose registers (R0 to R30) in AVR microcontrollers but why we can't load immediate value into SRAM apart from GPRs?

Comment: because it is RISC not CISC.

Answer (score 6):

I am not 100% sure about this, but from my research and experience this is what I get.

Most of the instructions of AVR architecture, if not all, use a 16-bit Opcode*. This means that the command has to specify the operation and the operands of the command using only 16 bits. 
The commands that involve immediate constants (ANDI, ORI, LDI, CPI, SBR, CBR, SUBI, SBCI etc.) have to hold an 8-bit costant value in the Opcode. The operation of the opcode is also usually defined using 4 bits. So we are left with only 4 bits out of the total 16. With 4 bits we can get a range of total 16 numbers. This is half the registers of an AVR controller. This is why you can only use 16 out of 32 registers.

The selection of the top half is a mystery to me as well. I can think of two reasons though.
1. Some instructions (like MUL) bound low registers R1:R0 as result registers.
2. Pointer registers that use indirect addressing (constants between 0-63) occupy top 6 registers (R26-R31).

Let me show you a couple of examples to make the Opcode more clear.

```
    ADD - Add without carry 
    Operation:   Rd <- Rd + Rr 
    Opcode:      0000 11rd dddd rrrr
    Description: We got five 'd' and five 'r'. With five bits you can get a total of 32 values. Which means that you can use any register available. 
    Example:
            ADD R5, R20. 
            Rd = R5     = 5     = 0 0101
            Rr = R20    = 20    = 1 0100
            The opcode would look like this 
            0000 1110 0101 0100  

    *************************************

    LDI - Load Immediate 
    Operation:   Rd <- K
    Opcode:      1110 KKKK dddd KKKK
    Description: We got eight 'K' and four 'd'.  
    Example:      
            LDI R18, 100 
            Rd  = R18   = 18-16=2   =      0010
            K   = 100   = 100       = 0110 0100
            The opcode would look like this 
            1110 0110 0010 0100
```

Source: 
http://www.microchip.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_instruction_list.html

*Opcode is the binary representation of the command in machine language. In short it's the language that processors really understand. The compiler's job is to translate a language that humans can easily understand (like C) to machine language.

Comment: The opcode is just the bits of the instruction word that says what instruction it is.  The immediate and register fields aren't part of the opcode.  (In a variable-length instruction set like x86, the opcode is often just the first byte, with later bytes specifying the operands).  Anyway, in AVR's `add` instruction, the opcode is the first 6 bits, while in `ldi` it's the first 4 bits.  The rest are operand bits.

Comment: You are correct. Opcode is indeed the identification bits and its size vary from instruction to instruction. I hope that readers will get the basic idea though.

Comment: It would be easy to say "instruction" or even "instruction word" to talk about the fixed-width 16 bits that represent the whole instruction.

Answer (score 3):

Most RISC machines are [load/store machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load/store_architecture): AVR, MIPS, SPARC, PowerPC, and I think ARM.  Every instruction has at least one register operand, and the only instructions that access (data) memory are load/store instructions with a register dst/src.

Any space for immediates in a store instruction is used for immediate displacements in the addressing mode, not for immediate data.

Remember that AVR instructions are fixed-width, unlike x86 where `mov r/m32, imm32` can use an arbitrary addressing mode for the destination (using up to 6 bytes for ModRM + SIB + disp32), and 4 bytes for the immediate.  Plus another 1 byte for the opcode.